# read multiple data in multiple files

Tags: java, io

I have a list of files in the directory C:\Users\Mahady\Desktop\Java 31122011\src\register\

they are like this....

> 100100545.txt
>
> 100545454.txt etc etc

in each file, file data are like this line by line:

> Bob
>
> 1234
>
> 4834
>
> London
>
> 9852
>
> 1

My question is, how do i read each files one by one in the directory and for each files read all lines except line 3. i would then like to merge this data in word and create letters. thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Do I get your salary if I do it for you? How about reading the IO tutorial? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: I wonder though if this would be better done simply using the scripting tools available in MS Word if what you desire is a Word merge. Visual Basic for Applications comes with Word and is quite powerful for just this sort of document and data manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\Mahady\\Desktop\\Java 31122011\\src\\register\\");
for (string fn : dir.list()) {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fn);
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        System.out.println (strLine);
    }
    in.close();
}
```

Obviously, you will need to add exception handling code around this skeletal implementation.

Comment: Has 'dasbinkenlight' successfully answered your question?  If so, please mark it as such so we can all benefit.

Answer (score 3):

Detailed Answer....

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileRead {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileReader fileReader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            File folder = new File("C:/Users/Mahady/Desktop/Java 31122011/src/register/");
            if (folder.isDirectory()) {
                for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
                    fileReader = new FileReader(file);
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
                    String line = null;
                    int lineCount = 0;
                    while (null != (line = bufferedReader.readLine())) {
                        lineCount++;
                        if (3 != lineCount) {
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (null != bufferedReader)
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this would help you.